They saw Perry as a payday
What is the meaning for "payday" of the last word of the paragraph below:
Milgram excoriated the accused for preying on Perry, especially physicians Plasencia and Chavea, whom she called "unscrupulous doctors who abused their position of trust because they saw Perry as a payday."

The two physicians probably obtained money easily from Perry, treating him as a source of easy money.  So payday means such a source.  This meaning is from context and likely can't be found in dictionaries.

Meaning of "payday":

whom she called "unscrupulous doctors who abused their position of trust because they saw Perry as a payday."

Here, "payday" refers to an opportunity to make financial gains. The phrase "saw Perry as a payday" implies that Plasencia and Chavez disregarded their ethical obligations, prioritizing financial profit over their duty of care and viewing Perry solely as a source of income.

Reference vocabulary.com.
paydays.
When you have a job, your payday is the day you get paid.
You can also use payday to mean a sudden success or influx of money, either earned or won:.
"That movie brought a huge payday to its producers.".
payday

